# Visual Studio 2022 can't publish Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, publish, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 When I try to publish an Azure App Service this happends:

[login fail](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1047968409268269187/1050575749398134784/azurefail.gif)

Basically the login window dissappear after I login and I can't do any progress with the publishing. I dont recieve any error message.

I tried with differents accounts but this happend with all of them.

I would like to have another way to publish it or fix this way.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to select in the next options:

- file
- Account setting
- then select accounts

[image]

And try system browser using the default browser with your account.

Comment: I tryed this and i was able to login but visual studio doesn't allows me to publish, just keep in the same window.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me (VS Community 2022 v17.5.3), it opens an auth window in my browser, I sign in and then it redirects to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/. However, nothing happens in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

As in the other answer select: File | Account Settings... then click 'Account Options'

[image]

Now select 'Windows authentication broker' from the dropdown.

I was having the exact same problem, and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Fixed it for me (Visual Studio Community 2022 v17.5.3). Thanks!